# Tkinter button doesn't respond (has no mouse over effect)

Tags: python-2.7, button, tkinter, twisted, exit

I'm writing a game that has info that is communicated from client to server and from server to client. One specific (non-playing) client is the monitor, which only displays the game board and players. This works fine, the only thing that doesn't work is the quit button on the GUI. A minor thing, but I would like it to work. :) Plus I think that there might be something pretty wrong with the code, even though it works.

I tried all kind of different commands (sys.exit, quit...) and nothing fixed it.

There's no error message, nothing happens with the button at all. No mouse over effect, nothing if I click it. Relevant code (I removed matrix and server logic because I think it's irrelevant - if it isn't I'll post it):

```
class Main():
def __init__(self, master):
    self.frame = Frame(master)
    self.frame.pack()
    # Has to be counted up by server class
    rounds = 0
    # Has to be communicated by server class. If numberwin == numberrobots,
    # game is won
    numberwin = 0
    numberrobots = 2

def draw(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'info'):
        self.info.destroy()
    if hasattr(self, 'quit'):
        self.quit.destroy()
    print "Main should draw this matrix %s" % self.matrix

    [...] lots of matrix stuff [...]

    # Pop-Up if game was won
    # TODO: Make GUI quittable
    if self.numberwin == self.numberrobots:
        self.top = Toplevel()
        self.msg = Message(self.top, text="This game was won!")
        self.msg.pack(side=LEFT)
        self.quittop = Button(
            self.top, text="Yay", command=self.frame.destroy)
        self.quittop.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    # TODO: Quit GUI
    self.quit = Button(self.frame, text="Quit", command=self.frame.destroy)
    self.quit.pack(side=BOTTOM)

    # Information on the game
    self.info = Label(
        self.frame, text="Rounds played: {}, Numbers of robots in win condition: {}".format(self.rounds, self.numberwin))
    self.info.pack(side=TOP)


def canvasCreator(self, numberrows, numbercolumns):
     # Game board
    self.canvas = Canvas(
        self.frame, width=numbercolumns * 100 + 10, height=numberrows * 100 + 10)
    self.canvas.pack()


class Agent(Protocol, basic.LineReceiver):
master = Tk()
main = Main(master)
# So first matrix is treated differently from later matrixes
flagFirstMatrix = 1

def connectionMade(self):
    msg = dumps({"type": "monitor"})
    self.sendLine(msg)
    print "Sent message:", msg

def dataReceived(self, data):
    # Decode the json dump
    print "Data received: %s" % data
    data = loads(data)
    self.main.matrix = np.matrix(data["positions"])
    self.main.goals = np.matrix(data["goals"])
    self.main.next_move_by_agent = data["next_move"]
    self.main.rounds = data["rounds"]
    self.main.numberwin = data["win_states"]
    if self.flagFirstMatrix == 1:
        self.main.numberrows, self.main.numbercolumns = self.main.matrix.shape
        self.main.canvasCreator(
            self.main.numberrows, self.main.numbercolumns)
        self.main.canvas.pack()
        self.flagFirstMatrix = 0
    self.main.canvas.delete(ALL)
    self.main.draw()
    self.master.update_idletasks()
    self.master.update()
```

Comment: It doesn't appear that you're calling `mainloop` anywhere. Is that true, or did you leave that code out?

Comment: No, I'm not... I just googled it and apparently you have to call mainloop even if things are displayed without it :)
I just tried some variants that seemed logical to me, but I can't figure out where to call mainloop and on what. Is it on master, because it is the Tk() instance or on main? And where should I call it?

Comment: typically you will call `mainloop` on the root window as the last line of code in your program.  Buttons work by responding to events. Events can't get sent or received without the event loop running. `mainloop` is the event loop.

Comment: I'm just not sure where the last line of my code is. I added some more code in class Agent to show my problem. The game board is drawn when new data is received from the server. I can't/shouldn't call mainloop there, I assume.
I tried the last line of class Agent, or the last line of class Main, and both yield an empty tk-window.

Answer (score 0):

First there is no indentation for class Agent, second for the quit button's "call back" `self.frame.destroy` is never defined so it doesn't do anything. If you meant tkinter destroy method try self.frame.destroy() or try explicitly defining it. You can also try calling either `fram.pack_forget()` or `fram.grid_forget()`

Add master.mainloop() to your last line in terms of the entire lines of code

Comment: Same question as above: What is my last line? If I put it as last line in Agent(), I get an empty tk-window.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however if I do this, I get an empty tk window again. I added it as the last line in class Agent, since only there master is a known variable. It is instantiated in Agent, so I can't adress it outside of the class. I assume you meant somewhere else?